# font color through rendering in typescript react

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, typescript, react-redux

Trying to set the font color through a variable inside a react component, but my `<span>` gives error:

```
Type '{ style: "color:yellow"; }' is not assignable to type 'HTMLProps<HTMLSpanElement>'
```

The yellow is just for testing, I will replace with {color} in the end.

```
import * as React from 'react';

    export interface SkillListItemProps {
        name: string
        color: string
       // Icons: 
    }

    interface SkillListItemState{
    }

    export class SkillListItem extends React.Component<SkillListItemProps,SkillListItemState>{
        public render(): JSX.Element{
            const {name, color} = this.props;
        return (
            <div className="SkillListItem"> 
                <span style="color:yellow">{name}</span>
            </div>
        )
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use an object, like this:

```
<span style={{color: "yellow"}}>{name}</span>
```

**JSFiddle Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/4wcmcpv3/1/**